# perl install Image::Imlib2 won't work on Mac OSX Mavericks

Tags: macos, perl, installation

I am trying to install [Image::Imlib2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Image::Imlib2) on my Mac running OSX Mavericks. I've installed Imlib2 using [brew](http://brew.sh/), but now I cannot actually install Image::Imlib2. Whenever I run the `make` command, I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/perl Build --makefile_env_macros 1
Building Image-Imlib2
env LD_RUN_PATH=/System/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE cc -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector -o blib/arch/auto/Image/Imlib2/Imlib2.bundle lib/Image/Imlib2.o ./lib/Image/Imlib2.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/imlib2/1.4.5/lib -lImlib2 -L/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.0.1/lib -lfreetype -lz -lbz2 -lX11 -lXext -ldl -lm
ld: library not found for -lX11
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error building blib/arch/auto/Image/Imlib2/Imlib2.bundle from lib/Image/Imlib2.o ./lib/Image/Imlib2.o at /System/Library/Perl/5.16/ExtUtils/CBuilder/Base.pm line 312.
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It says that it cannot find the library for -lX11. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: this might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047680/ld-cant-find-x11-library-on-osx-leopard