# ld: library not found for -lXext

Tags: c, macos

I'm trying to compile DOOM (sources from here: https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM) on OSX. With some modification I reached almost the end of the makefile, but I have a problem, in makefile I have

```
CC=  gcc
CFLAGS=-g -Wall -DNORMALUNIX -DLINUX 
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/X11R6/lib
LIBS=-lXext -lX11 -lnsl -lm
```

and the complete output of make now is:

```
gcc   -g -Wall -DNORMALUNIX -DLINUX  -L/usr/X11R6/lib linux/doomdef.o 
linux/doomstat.o linux/dstrings.o linux/i_system.o linux/i_sound.o 
linux/i_video.o linux/i_net.o linux/tables.o linux/f_finale.o linux/f_wipe.o 
linux/d_main.o linux/d_net.o linux/d_items.o linux/g_game.o linux/m_menu.o 
linux/m_misc.o linux/m_argv.o linux/m_bbox.o linux/m_fixed.o linux/m_swap.o 
linux/m_cheat.o linux/m_random.o linux/am_map.o linux/p_ceilng.o 
linux/p_doors.o linux/p_enemy.o linux/p_floor.o linux/p_inter.o 
linux/p_lights.o linux/p_map.o linux/p_maputl.o linux/p_plats.o 
linux/p_pspr.o linux/p_setup.o linux/p_sight.o linux/p_spec.o 
linux/p_switch.o linux/p_mobj.o linux/p_telept.o linux/p_tick.o 
linux/p_saveg.o linux/p_user.o linux/r_bsp.o linux/r_data.o linux/r_draw.o 
linux/r_main.o linux/r_plane.o linux/r_segs.o linux/r_sky.o linux/r_things.o 
linux/w_wad.o linux/wi_stuff.o linux/v_video.o linux/st_lib.o 
linux/st_stuff.o linux/hu_stuff.o linux/hu_lib.o linux/s_sound.o 
linux/z_zone.o linux/info.o linux/sounds.o linux/i_main.o \

    -o linux/linuxxdoom -lXext -lX11 -lnsl -lm
ld: library not found for -lXext
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [linux/linuxxdoom] Error 1
```

It can not find any of theese 4 libraries. in /usr/X11R6/lib/ I have libXext.6.dylib, libX11.6.dylib and many others, but I don't know how to use them here :/
any tips?

EDIT: I'm downloading XQuartz for osx, I don't know if I need it because I have x11 folders, but who knows, I'll try to install it anyway
EDIT2: I installed XQuartz and now it almost works! Anyway I miss -lnsl library!, but I have the -lm.

Comment: Does `libXext.so` exist? What distribution are you using (*assuming Linux*).

Comment: OP said that the OS is OS X

Comment: It's OSX 10.11 El Capitan, and libXext.so does not exists, I have libXext.dylib that is a link to libXext.6.dylib

Comment: No softlink for `libXext.dylib`?  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6784033/4756299 for an answer that shows similar softlinks for `libX11.dylib`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've solved my problem installing XQuartz. Then I managed other few things that blocked compilation and it compiled to the end! :D
Now I'm trying to run it!